# Multiple Zend_Mail configurations in application.ini

Tags: zend-mail, zend-framework

I'm am using Zend Framework.

I need to put multiple mail configurations in application.ini for Zend_Mail (using Zend_Application_Resource_Mail).  Is it possible to do this using the standard classes in Zend Framework or do I need to create my own class?

I am using the latest stable version of Zend Framework.

Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 4):

It does not appear to be possible to set multiple configurations for Zend_Mail with Zend_Application_Resource_Mail.

You could add the various configurations to application.ini but you will have to write your own class/functions to make the desired configuration active.

The things that are set by Zend_Application_Resource_Mail that you will have to override are `Zend_Mail::setDefaultTransport($newTransport);`, `Zend_Mail::setDefaultReplyTo($email);`, and `Zend_Mail::setDefaultFrom($email);`.

I tested something and found an easy thing you can do.

Set up your different configurations like this in application.ini:

```
mail_config.mail_test.transport.type = smtp
mail_config.mail_test.transport.host = "smtp.example.com"
mail_config.mail_test.transport.auth = login
mail_config.mail_test.transport.username = myUsername
mail_config.mail_test.transport.password = myPassword

mail_config.mail_test.defaultFrom.email = john@example.com
mail_config.mail_test.defaultFrom.name = "John Doe"
mail_config.mail_test.defaultReplyTo.email = Jane@example.com
mail_config.mail_test.defaultReplyTo.name = "Jane Doe"
```

Note how we are setting up options under `mail_config`.  This will be the set of options to apply.  `mail_test` is an example configuration.  You can have multiple by setting `mail_config.mail_test2`, `mail_config.corporate_mail`, or `mail_config.production` etc.

Next, create an empty class that extends from `Zend_Application_Resource_Mail`.  Preferably, it should be named and placed so it can be autoloaded.

The class:

```
<?php

class Application_Service_MailSettings extends Zend_Application_Resource_Mail { }
```

Now, here is how to override the default mail configuration easily with something else.

This example assumes you are in a controller:

```
    // get the bootstrap, so we can get mail_config options
    $bootstrap = $this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap');
    $options   = $bootstrap->getOption('mail_config');

    // initialize the resource loader with the options from mail_config.mail_test
    $mailSettings = new Application_Service_MailSettings($options['mail_test']);
    $mailSettings->init();  // call init() so the settings are applied

    // now the default transport, from, and reply to are set using mail_config.mail_test options.

    // to use a different set of options, just do
    // $mailSettings = new Application_Service_MailSettings($options['other_config');
```

This should accomplish what you want with very little new code.