# Zend_Mail, appropriate way of handling numerous configurations of headers for system notifications?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm using Zend_Mail to handle my application's automated system e-mails.  However, there are numerous configurations, ie (sign-up emails come from info@me.com, customer service emails come from customer_service@me.com, etc.).  I don't want to duplicate code within my action controllers when setting up the email headers, but I also don't want to end up having a mail factory with dozens of static methods to retrieve all the various configurations of e-mails.  How should I proceed?

I'm thinking about just creating class constants (within a mailFactory class) for the name and e-mail addresses of all the different system e-mail addresses, and then just configuring the e-mail headers within the action controllers until I find configurations that are re-used often at which point i'll create a static method to retrieve that type of e-mail.

Comment: I answered a similar question not too long ago and the solution may be of interest to you.  Basically it gives a shortcut way to have multiple default mail configurations in your application.ini file.  Hopefully it can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8274476/multiple-zend-mail-configurations-in-application-ini/8275861#8275861

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you create a class, something like "MailHelper" with a function "getMail()".

In the getMail() you create a Zend_Mail instance based on options you can provide to the getMail. You could then simply make a switch case and set options on demand.

This will ensure you have only 1 location to create Zend_Mail instances with maximum flexibility!